# Using higher voltage rails than an op amp is rated for

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm going to try this when I get home, but I was curious if anyone has tried this. Most op amps are rated for ~ +15V to -15V. What would happen if I used +30V to -30V, but never amplified above the +15V to -15V range. Overall, I am looking to reduce power supply complexity. This is for just for testing, not production.

Answer (score 4):

You will damage the opamp, possibly destroy it. Absolute maximum ratings will probably say +/- 18 V, beyond which they'll note that damage may occur. Since you'll not be exceeding the maximum by a few volts, but by 24 V no less, I have little hopes of your opamp surviving.

Comment: I saw a guy do this in a lab once. The op amp made a crack like a gun shot, and flew up and out of the breadboard. I'm pretty sure he also soiled himself.

Comment: @Matt - Aerospace electronics! Do you know what voltage that was?

Comment: It is called a scent generator ;o)

Comment: Thinking back on it, it may have been a power op amp. Regardless, there were two 60V/6A supplies on the bench. We were working on a couple audio amplifiers that were rail to rail, so it could have been 120V. I don't know of any op amp that would survive that.

Comment: @Matt - Apex (now Cirrus Logic) has opamps for several hundreds of volts. [This one](http://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/PA89U_L.pdf) will give you a 1140 Vpp output. Maybe an idea for Danny? :-)

Comment: My word, that is a monster. Just looked the price up as well, better hope he doesn't put it in backwards. :)

Comment: @Matt - Yeah, I saw it too: 931 dollar! :-(

Comment: I once had a PIC16C84 which I accidentally powered with 9 volts, and it actually worked at that voltage.  Once I powered it with 9 volts, however, it would no longer work below about 6.  It might have been interesting to see how long it would have kept working, except that tried to reprogram it; it seemed to erase, but not program.  Perhaps I could have rigged the programmer to power it with 9 volts to see if it could program that way, but I wasn't that interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is one of the many ways to make a [magic smoke generator.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/inio/1388860549/)  
   Ones made in this manner are extremely reliable and consistent in making magic smoke.
2. Why would you?
   Reducing the power supplies to the correct limits may take as little as 4 resistors.
   (Two per rail, in a divider that is "stiff" compared to op amp current.

BUT no matter what is required to provide power supplies in spec , that is what is required.